# Is it possible to get Ghost in first mission without taking down the guards?

Tags: achievements, dishonored

In first mission, there is a place where you have to blow up the prison gates. I know you can knock down two nearby guards and still get the Ghost achievement. Is it also possible without the take down? There is smoke and chaos right after the blast - is it possible to use that to sneak through the doors without being spotted?

I tried it, but have had no luck so far and I'm quite sure that I'm not being spotted anywhere else. I've also tried to hide in containers and dark spots around the room right after the blast (to wait until they get calm again), but guards are always aware of my location anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it is very possible to do this, as seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbwxbeYxamg).

To summarize what happens in the video: It looks like you will need to exploit jumping over walls and sneaking closely behind the guards to get into the prison yard. Once you make it to the control room, you are able to climb onto the pipes (not sure if this was actually intended or not, but it looks like it works!). You can use your weapon on the pipes to lure the guards away from the door, so that when you blow it up, you can quickly dash through the opening and jump into the water without being caught.

Comment: Great video. I knew the guy on the bottom of stairs was the problem in that room, because when I knocked him down I could make it, but I would never though I could lure him away and close the inner gate. Definitely non standard solution :) Thanks!